# js realtime calculation with ruby variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to display in realtime the total between a ruby variable times an input field populated by a user.

I tried the bellow js but I'm getting `NaN`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".total_time").keypress(function() {
        var fee = '<%=@user.fees%>';
        fee = parseFloat(fee);
        var time = $('.total_time').val();
        time = parseInt(time);
        $(".total_charge").text(fee * time);
    });
});
```

Here are is the input field:

```
<input class="form-control total_time" name="total_time" placeholder="2" type="text"></input>
```

Comment: Have a look at your generated source to be sure the value is being substituted properly. Usually `var fee = <%= JSON.dump(@user.fees) %>` is the safest method to include in JavaScript.

Comment: With console debugging tools I was able to check the Values of fee and time. `time` does get converted to integer but fee is `NaN`. I don't get why. It's a decimal in the DB and all users have 100 set up as a default value. So it's not like it's would return null

Answer (score 1):

The issue was using the `<%= %>`erb containers to expose the value.

I had to change the code to use `data`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".total_time").keyup(function() {
    var fees = $('#user_fees').data('source');
    fee = parseFloat(fees);
    var time = $('.total_time').val();
    time = parseInt(time);
    var total = fees*time
    $(".total_charge").text(total);
  });
});
```

Comment: Putting things in `data` is usually a much more elegant way of doing this.